# How to send scheduled message in kakao talk channel

Tags: bots, chatbot

I am new to kakao bot development. I done some development in kakao talk channel like skill creation and response message but i don't know how to send message to user on scheduled time. I like to send news message to user in my channel daily at 9 o clock. May i know how to send it. Message will be differ based on user preferences

Answer (score 0):

You can't. it's blocked by their policy. The only way you can send a message (except replying) is using a bot(which is against their EULA), or paying money to send a marketing ad.

I know that you probably solved your problem, but I'm leaving this reply here for future travelers to see

Comment: ya thanks. I too posted solution which i have used. This may help other developers

Answer (score 0):

I found solution and implemented in my project. I hope this may help for other developers. Using BizTalk subscription we can send Biz message to users.

BizTalk website - https://www.biztalk.co.kr/html/main/index_1.php

Biz message details - https://www.biztalk.co.kr/html/bizMessage/message.php